# UK Visa Refusal due to no family members in home country

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

Me and my wife planning to visit UK as tourist. My UK tourist visa refusal letter give some valid observations, which I am going to address in second attempt. However, one observation, I hard to find out suitable answer, is that " You have not shown from the supporting documents you have any family members living in Pakistan or other countries and therefore consider you have very little way of ties to provide you with enough incentive to leave the UK on completion of your proposed visit". Now, my family situation is such that I have two daughters, both married and living with their husbands. My only son is doing his studies in UK. So, in application at the filed "Evidence of family members remaining in your home country whilst you travel" , I had no other choice except to write NIL. So, is there any suggestion, how to address this observation.

Comment: Elderly parents? If you don’t have any close family remaining behind you can’t satisfy this, however you can look to present other strong ties such as stable job, property

Comment: You have not mentioned where your daughters are living.

Comment: @Traveller: I have elderly parents and property as well, both were mentioned in the application.

Comment: @WeatherVane, My both daughters are married and living outside my home city.

Comment: My point is whether they live in your home *country*. Why did you write "NIL" when your parents are mentioned, and you have property? You need to lay it on thick.

Comment: @hf20 In that case, it would seem you need to provide proof of their existence and relationship to you with your next application. Eg your and their birth certificates, Electoral Photo ID Card etc

Comment: What about grandchildren?

Comment: In your next application, mention your parents, provide proof they exist and provide an explanation for why you didn't mention them in the first application.

Comment: Thanks @Traveller, and others....... I have catered all your points and submitted fresh application last night....giving details and elaboration about my elderly parents and my daughters and will give evidence in supporting documents of parents recent medical treatments which I am getiing and passport copies, plus both daughters residential status of one living in UAE and other in home country but another city. And will also attached her medical document showing she is in family way expected delivery in June this year, considering all these as strong reason for family ties.